# Is there a way to use global templates in expression engine?

Tags: templates, template-partials

By default, each template in expression engine is an entire template. Is there a way to set a global template, and have each template be inserted as the content section of that template?

ie.
`.template.php`:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {embed:currentpagecontent}
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only way I can think of doing it is to have common elements and embed them on ***every*** template - like so:

```
{embed:'.header.php'}
{embed:'.navbar.php'}

<h1>ipsum lorem</h1>

{embed:'.footer.php'}
```

it just seems messy having the same prefix and suffix on ***every*** template

(nb. this question sounds annoyingly confusing due the dual meaning of the word 'template' in expression engine!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common question and there is a technique you can use with the add-on "Stash." It's already been described and documented multiple times.

Check out the selected answer for this other, similar question: [How to use a common template for all pages?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-to-use-a-common-template-for-all-pages#answer-343)

Comment: perfect - i'll check this out now!

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely *could* have a single template. Just make 1 template, set it as the 'homepage' of your site then within that apply whatever logic you wish to pull in different embeds or snippets. Though I think it would become a bit messy fairly quickly for anything but the most basic site. It's much simpler to use different template groups.

What is the other meaning of "template" in EE? There's only 1 meaning of template as far as I'm aware.

Comment: so the recommended approach is to have boilerplate sections that are common to the whole site in hidden templates, and {embed}ding them on every page?

Comment: (and i just meant that ee templates are tied directly to routing/controller logic - something that i've always tried to keep separate from view logic. it's confusing because i want to keep the routing logic of 'template groups : templates', but not have duplicated content on *every* 'template' in the whole site)

Comment: I don't know if it's "recommended" or not but I tend to create partials for things like site headers, footers etc. I probably wouldn't try to do everything on a single template simply because the conditional logic would get over complex for most of the things I build with EE.